# How do you debug the python portions of a PyObjC-based app?

Tags: xcode, pyobjc

I've got a trivial PyObjC app up and running. Source here: https://github.com/ipmcc/DebugPython

I can build and run this app from Xcode, and I can (as expected) set breakpoints in the Objective-C portions of the code (main.m) and Xcode stops at them just fine. However, while it will let me add breakpoints to the python code, the debugger does not stop at them.

Is it possible to do source level debugging (preferably inside Xcode, but maybe elsewhere?) of the python portions of a PyObjC-based app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to debug PyObjC programs by adding print statements/logging, and if that fails by using pdb (from the command-line).